# What happens to votes if I delete my question?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

A user recently posted an answer to my question, which revealed to me a simple oversight in my code.. a type-o.   The question may be useful at some point to somebody, though I wonder about the ramifications of marking it for deletion.

I don't want to take away another member's good karma for giving a useful and factually correct answer, but perhaps that's just the way it goes.

So my question is, what happens to the points another member earns when being upvoted, or chosen for Accepted Answer, if I delete the question?

Comment: If you're referring to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14510383), I wouldn't worry about that user keeping reputation. It's too localized and deserves to be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer normally doesn't get deleted permanently it is still visible by 10k users,

but The reputation goes away.  It is as thought the answer never existed

If the answer comes back so does the rep.

as a note, I don't think that you will be able to personally delete that question on your own, considering that there's an up-voted answer posted to it.

Comment: You can't delete a question if any of the answers have upvotes on them. (unless the question is closed)

Comment: I've voted the question be closed (localization).  It needs one more  close vote before I can delete it.  Thanks.  Q: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14510383